# Centered divs are off-center?

Tags: html, css

I've got a 6x4 array of 150px divs, each with a 5px margin (imagine Metro UI). I've also got a modal div. The square divs are all `display: inline-block`, centered with `text-align` in a parent div, and there's a line break after every 6 (to make the 6x4 grid). When my modal (also centered, with `margin`) pops up, it is slightly unaligned with the tiles that are also centered. Why might this be? This wouldn't be a big deal, but it aligns with the square tiles below it, and it looks horrible having everything 1-2 pixel(s) off. Could there be a difference in `text-align: center` and `margin: auto` causing this?

From the HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<br />
<div id="tile11">

</div>
<div id="tile12">

</div>
<div id="tile13">

</div>
<div id="tile14">

</div>
<div id="tile15">

</div>
<div id="tile16">

</div>
<br />
<div id="tile21">

</div>
<div id="tile22">

</div>
...........
<div id="tile46">

</div>
</div>
```

From CSS:

```
#container {
background: #000000;
width: 1000px;
height: 680px;
z-index: 1;
text-align: center;
margin: 10px auto 0px auto;
}

#tile44 {
background: #333333;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
margin: 5px;
display: inline-block;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: with some code of yours it might be possible to help you

Comment: Maybe it just sounds weird from your description because we have no example but why would you use "text-align" to center your div elements? I would suggest to put them into a container and align that one with margin: 0 auto.

Comment: Definitely could do with a jsFiddle, though off the top of my head it sounds like your divs aren't actually centred on the screen - their margin may have pushed them to the side a bit, giving the appearance that it's your dialog that looks off..

Comment: Have you got CSS for every tile? Looks like you would be far better off doing a list.. or is #tile44 your dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this as a starter:

http://jsfiddle.net/HdHRe/10/

```
#container {
   background: #000000;
   width: 960px;
   height: 680px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 5px;
   overflow: auto;
}

#container div {
   background: #333333;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   margin: 5px;
   float: left;
}
```

​

I think its a better way to create your grid. Now we need to know where you want to display your modal window.

Comment: Turns out `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` was my only real problem, should be better now. Thanks

Comment: Here is a slightly improved version with a modal (click anywhere on the container) over all tiles: http://jsfiddle.net/HdHRe/22/